# Issue getting element to display on page Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

context:

1. element x clicked (initiates request)

*in the background, request intercepted by javascript, default action prevented (submit form), new element (element y) added to page (confirmation dialog)*

The problem is that it seems that the request is not being intercepted by the javascript and element y, is in turn not added to the page.

Thoughts as to where I may be going wrong here? (functions as expected when tested manually)

```
tr = first('tr', text: object)
tr.find('input[value="Delete"]').click
find('.popover-content').find('a', text: 'Yes').click

1) x
     Failure/Error: find('.popover-content').find('a', text: 'Yes').click
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css ".popover-content"
     # ./spec/features/x_panel_spec.rb:1029:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Have you set `js: true` on the example and what javascript driver are you using? Default selenium, capybara-webkit, or poltergeist?

Comment: @infused yes, and oh, sorry, I do believe selenium! also, thank you so much for your help so far!

Comment: Make sure you are following the recommendations at https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#asynchronous-javascript-ajax-and-friends and update your question with the code for the failing test.

Comment: I think you will need to add an expectation after the first click to force Capybara to wait for the js to add the popover.  Maybe something like `expect(page).to have_content('.popover-content a')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: was an issue related to the on document ready not being called (and in turn a portion of the javascript not being called) in certain contexts, solution was to use on window load function